stabilityai/stablelm-2-zephyr-1_6b SLM doesn't work properly after fine-tuning
I am trying to teach the SLM stabilityai/stablelm-2-zephyr-1_6b to classify if a sentence is a hate speech or not. I have a DataFrame with 100 examples (I have lot more this is just a sample to begin with). The text looks like this:
"<|user|>\nIs the next sentence is hate speech: \"{msg}\"? <|im_end|>"

and the labels looks like this:
'<|assistant|>\nNo, it is not a hate speech <|im_end|>' or '<|assistant|>\nYes, it is a hate speech <|im_end|>'
I am using lightning package to wrap the model and its fine-tuning. I had set the variable model to be lightning containing self.model and self.tokenizer, my loss function is: NllLossBackward0
I am doing one epoch and it's absolutely enough. I start with loss of 19 and finish with loss close to zero.
However, after training when I am trying to generate code using this code:
prompt = [{'role': 'user', 'content': 'Is the next sentence is a hate speech: "We should kill all Jews!"?'}]
inputs = model.tokenizer.apply_chat_template(
    prompt,
    max_length=512,
    add_generation_prompt=True,
    return_tensors='pt', 
    padding="max_length"
)

tokens = model.model.generate(
    inputs,
    max_new_tokens=512,
    temperature=0.5,
    do_sample=True
)

print(model.tokenizer.decode(tokens[0]))

All I get is:
The attention mask and the pad token id were not set. As a consequence, you may observe unexpected behavior. Please pass your input's `attention_mask` to obtain reliable results.
Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:100257 for open-end generation.
<|user|>
Is the next sentence is a hate speech: "We should kill all Jews!"?<|im_end|>
<|assistant|>
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
